# Change default math font in Powerpoint

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

The default math font for MS Powerpoint 2016 is "Cambria Math". In some cases, I want to change it (e.q. "XITS Math").

I found a solution for MS Word ([Select a different math font in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1114697/select-a-different-math-font-in-microsoft-word)). However, it cannot apply for Powerpoint because the Equation Option dialog in Powerpoint differs from the one in Word.

Here is Equation Options dialog in Powerpoint:

[image: Equation Option dialog in Powerpoint]

Here is Equation Options dialog in Word:

[image: Equation Option dialog in Word]

How to show the full options dialog for Powerpoint like in Word?

Comment: If you want the fuill options dialog, you'll probably have to create your equations in Word then copy/paste to PowerPoint.

Comment: I did it. However, when I paste it to Powerpoint, it automatically converts to the default math font of Powerpoint (even I tried three paste options: keep source, match destination, keep text only).

Comment: I don't have any appropriate math fonts other than Cambria Math installed on my 2016 box so can't test this, but after selecting the equation in Word, copy it, then in PPT, use Paste Special and choose As Word Object or similar.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-change-the-default-font-in-equation-editor/52732d01-da0b-4a0b-809e-779ed1148938) post, Cambria Math is currently the only supported font. The user on that post recommends selecting your equation after you have finished, click on the Normal Text option to turn it to plain text, and then apply your desired font.